# Поле Bit. Операции ввода и вывода

Tags: php, mysql

Хочу хранить биты в поле MySQL.

```
    CREATE TABLE user(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,name VARCHAR(15) 
NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(id),code bit);
```

Теперь хочу внести в него данные '0001', '1001', '1101' ,'0011' итд.

```
 INSERT INTO user(name,code) VALUES('WRITE3',b'0111');
```

при выводе через SELECT * FROM user получаю специфицеские симоволы....

-Как получить  число после битовой операции с ячейкой?

Псевдокод:

```
 CAST(name|0010,SIGNED)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BIN(), читаем [здесь](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/bit-field-literals.html)

```
SELECT id,name,BIN(code) from user;
```

Comment: Буду учить.Благодарен за ссылку.